# Yii2 из массива объектов получить массив уникальных

Tags: yii2, gridview

Есть массив объектов Юзеров (User) со свойством Name
как их сгруперовать, посчитать повторяемые и передать в 
    GridView

> Валера 2
>    Сергей 5
>    Коля 8
>    Вася 1

Comment: Запросом или перебирать в цикле массив объектов и считать

Answer (score 1):

Должно работать:

```
$users = User::find()
    ->select('name, COUNT(*) AS count')
    ->groupBy('name')
    ->asArray() // Добавьте вывод массивом или же публичное свойство `count` в модель `User`
    ->all();
```

Для каждого объекта вернет два поля `name` и `count`. В `count` будет содержаться кол-во сгруппированных объектов.

Comment: сначала я сделал так ->select(['name'], 'DISTINCT'), а потом по Вашему, но поля 'count' нет, откуда же ему взяться?

Comment: @ProMix Я поправил, теперь у Вас все должно работать, я проверил у себя.

Comment: @ProMix Модель по всей видимости съедает доп. поля. Если выводить массивом, то всё есть.

Comment: Чтобы модель не съедала, надо в класс модели добавить свойство `public $count;`

Comment: @fedornabilkin Да, как вариант:)